# Save two specific worksheets in a new workbook without formulas but keeping the design

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I've got a workbook where I am creating a button that allows to save two specific sheets without formula's (the purpose being that the sheets are going to be send to partners and costumers). I would like the sheets to be saved in a single document somewhere on my computer, and still have the current "design" with colors, setup etc.

I've currently written this code, which does everything that I've described, except deleting the formulas...

```
Sub SaveAsValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Worksheets(Array("frontpage", "mobile")).Copy After:= ws.Worksheets

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:= "C:XXXX" & "NAME", FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook
.Close savechanges = False
End With
End Sub
```

Hope you can help :-)

Comment: Loop through the worksheets in the new workbook, and set the `.UsedRange.Value =  .UsedRange.Value` on each sheet.

Comment: `ws.Worksheets` looks off btw.

Comment: Regarding your bonus question - spaces in worksheet names should not be an issue. What is the issue you're having?

Comment: @BigBen Regarding the bonus question, it get the error message "subscription out of range" when using my sheets with spaces in them"

Comment: That means you haven't typed the worksheet name correctly.

Comment: @BigBen Regarding your first comment, it's pretty crucial that I make it an automatic proces, as the model will be used by other co-workers who are not experienced in Excel whatsoever

Comment: Yes - I'm giving you a hint for how to do it in VBA.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. For example: `Worksheets(Array("front page", "mobile")).Copy` works for me.

Comment: Alright, I figured out the problem for the bonus question. There was a space at the end of the sheet name.. @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

I have a sheet I use something similar for, I'll adjust the code a bit to work with your scenario. If you don't want the settings to change, delete the `TurnOnFunctions` & `TurnOffFunctions` subs.

This code will only break the links, not necessarily all the formulas. So if a formula references another spreadsheet it will be a static value; however, if it is a simple formula that stays within the spreadsheet it will stay that way.

Also add your workbook name to the respective area.

```
Sub NewWorkbooks()
'This will make seperate workbooks for each of the tabs listed
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Call TurnOffFunctions
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In Workbooks("YOUR WORKBOOK NAMR"). _
Worksheets(Array("frontpage", "mobile"))
        ws.Copy
        Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
        With NewBook
            Call break_links(NewBook)
            .SaveAs Filename:="C:XXXX" & "NAME", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
Next

Call TurnOnFunctions

End Sub
Sub break_links(ByRef wb As Workbook)
Dim Links As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Links = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
        wb.BreakLink _
        Name:=Links(i), _
        Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next i
End If

End Sub
Private Sub TurnOffFunctions()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub
Private Sub TurnOnFunctions()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You can use yours too with this mod (untested):

```
Sub SaveAsValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Worksheets(Array("frontpage", "mobile")).Copy After:= ws.Worksheets

Call break_links ActiveWorkbook

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:= "C:XXXX" & "NAME", FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook
.Close savechanges = False
End With
End Sub

Sub break_links(ByRef wb As Workbook)
Dim Links As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Links = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
        wb.BreakLink _
        Name:=Links(i), _
        Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! what do I enter in the "YOUR WORKBOOK NAME" ?

Comment: When I try the second method, I get the error message: "Compile error: Method or data member not found" with a reference to "ws.Worksheets"  in the end of the 3rd line

Comment: @AndreasVange - get rid of the `After:= ws.Worksheets` entirely...

Comment: @BigBen Done! But now I get the error message "compile error: Argument not optional" referring to line 4, "Call break_links"

Comment: Should be: `break_links ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Alright, it seems to work now, but the second page still contains formula

Comment: It appears that various places will have the formula deleted, while it's maintained in other places(cells)

Comment: @AndreasVange refer to my note that this breaks the links to other spreadsheets, keeps formulas that refer internally. You can copy and paste the whole sheet as values onto itself to maintain formatting but only keep static values.

Comment: @MarkS.Aaah, I see now. The thing is, that I will probably need to make it fully automatic. I'm connecting the macro to a button that any user of the document can press to create a copy without any formula whatsoever. The reason that I need it to be fully automatic is that the "template" is not mainly for me, but for various key account managers in the firm, and they require that it's fully automatic.

Comment: @AndreasVange yeah so use a macro do copy and paste the sheet as values so it will keep everything static...